# MSSQL 2016 express edition download

Tags: sql-server, sql

Been looking everywhere for this download
but can't find it

?MS didn't not released the Express edition ???
?Did they had any problems creating the express edition SKU for the release date (today, 2016.06.01)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is there.

Also, Links for Download: [**Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Express**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679)

- https://www.microsoft.com/en/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

[image: MS SQL 2016]

Comment: Yep.. thanks...
the direct link is 
"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679"

Comment: All links are broken.

Answer (score 0):

And here is the direct link to download the express version:

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52679
```